# Using Firestore from a JobIntentService: Failed to gain exclusive lock to the Firestore client's offline persistence

Tags: firebase, kotlin, background-process, google-cloud-firestore, jobintentservice

Whenever I exit the app while I have an alarm set and the alarm goes off while the app is "DEAD" I get an Exception while trying to update a field in Firestore.

The code works when the app is running in the foreground so I really have no clue of what is going on. Either way, here is the code for 2 functions which get called from the JobIntentService which is in turn created from a BroadcastReceiver:

```
private val firestoreInstance: FirebaseFirestore by lazy { FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() }

    fun updateTaskCompletedSessions(taskDocRefPath: String, completedSessions: Int){
        val taskDocRef = firestoreInstance.document(taskDocRefPath)
        taskDocRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
            documentSnapshot.reference
                    .update(mapOf("completedSessions" to completedSessions))
        }
    }

    fun updateTaskSessionProgress(taskDocRefPath: String, sessionProgress: String){
        val taskDocRef = firestoreInstance.document(taskDocRefPath)
        taskDocRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
            documentSnapshot.reference
                    .update(mapOf("sessionProgress" to sessionProgress))
        }
    }
```

The full error goes as follows:

> Failed to gain exclusive lock to the Firestore client's offline persistence.
>
> This generally means you are using Firestore from multiple processes in your app. Keep in mind that multi-process Android apps execute the code in your `Application` class in all processes, so you may need to avoid initializing Firestore in your `Application` class. If you are intentionally using Firestore from multiple processes, you can only enable offline persistence (i.e. call `setPersistenceEnabled(true)`) in one of them.

I will appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm happy to announce that I found a solution! I was using two consequently firing JobIntentServices - one for `completedSessions`, the other for `sessionProgress`. (Bad design, I know...)

When I played around with it and made just ONE JobIntentService to call both of these functions, the exception is gone which makes perfect sense.