# Firestore offline persistence error when using workmanager

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-workmanager

I'm using a `WorkManger` to retrieve information periodically from my `Firestore` database when the app is in the background and foreground. This information is used to update the UI based on a status (so different statuses adds or removes different parts of the UI). On first run this works well, however, once the app is in the background and the `WorkManager` tries to run, it crashes with this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to gain exclusive lock to the Firestore client's offline persistence. This generally means you are using Firestore from multiple processes in your app. Keep in mind that multi-process Android apps execute the code in your Application class in all processes, so you may need to avoid initializing Firestore in your Application class. If you are intentionally using Firestore from multiple processes, you can only enable offline persistence (i.e. call setPersistenceEnabled(true)) in one of them.
```

Originally I did: `FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();` in all activities and fragments because the error stated it was a bad idea to initialise inside the application class. However, I still received the error and I even tried creating just a single instance of the initialisation inside the application class like so:

```
public FirebaseFirestore getFirestore(){
    if(firestore == null){
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    }
    return firestore;
}
```

But I'm still seeing this error whenever the `WorkManager` runs. I've tried the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48973787/using-firestore-from-a-jobintentservice-failed-to-gain-exclusive-lock-to-the-fi) since it's a bit similar but it didn't resolve the error. I also saw somewhere that firestore can't be called on a separate thread, or I could be mistaken.

I'm fairly certain it has to do with how I initialize and access the firestore instance but I'm not sure how to fix it. I tried using separate initializations in each activity, fragment and service where it's being used, with no luck.

**EDIT**

Worker Class:

```
public class PopulateThemeCache extends Worker {

@Inject
FirebaseMethods mFirebaseMethods;

private ThemeDao themeDao;

private String themeKey;

public PopulateThemeCache() {
    FireApp.getApp().getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
    themeDao = PictematicOfflineCache.getDatabase(getApplicationContext()).themeDao();
}

@Override
@NonNull
public Result doWork() {
    try{

        Query query = FireApp.getApp().getFirestore().collection("themes").orderBy("start_time");

        query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                 //executed code here
            }
        });

        Overall overall = new Overall();

        query = FireApp.getApp().getFirestore().collection("profile_posts");

        query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                //executed code
            }
        });
        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }catch (Throwable throwable){
        Log.e("PopulateThemeCache", "Error caching", throwable);
        return Result.FAILURE;
    }
}}
```

MainActivity onCreate:

```
PeriodicWorkRequest request = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(PopulateThemeCache.class, 2, TimeUnit.HOURS)
            .addTag("Theme_Update")
            .build();

WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(request);
```

I integrated firebase using the Android Studio Assistant tool. The above worker class queries a `theme` node and checks for the currently available theme and updates a room database.

Comment: I am having no problems with WorkManager and Firestore in my app.  Note that `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()` isn't initialization - it's merely accessing a singleton.  Init normally happens automatically in a ContentProvider added by Firebase libraries.  How did you integrate Firebase into your app?  Some way other than the google-sevices plugin?

Comment: Also please edit your question to show how you're using WorkManager and describe how you are configuring it to do work.

Comment: @DougStevenson I added the worker class. Also, I integrated firebase using the Android Studio Assistant tool.

Comment: Do you have any other processes defined in your final merged manifest at all?

Comment: @DougStevenson no I do not think so. I could add it to the question if that helps

Comment: I suggest filing a bug report with the code for the smallest possible app that solidly reproduces this error.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Have you tried the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47056482/5861618)?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes no I have not. I updated the dependency to the latest version alpha07 and I haven't received the error since but now it doesn't seem to be doing the work, I never receive a notification after it has finished checking the database for a new theme

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find any solution?